# android nested custom control xml attributes

Tags: android, xml, custom-controls

I'm building an android compound control and nesting it into another compound control.  The nested control, ThirtySecondIncrement, is a simple incrementing control with a minus then text field then plus so you can raise or lower the increment.  I've made this control more general for my app allowing for a simple counter or 30-second increments or 1-minute increments.  Here is the xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <integer name="counter_simple">0</integer>
        <integer name="counter_30sec">1</integer>
        <integer name="counter_1min">2</integer>
        <declare-styleable name="ThirtySecondIncrement">
            <attr name="countertype" format="integer"/>
            <attr name="maxcount" format="integer"/>
        </declare-styleable>
        <declare-styleable name="IntervalEdit">
            <attr name="label" format="string"/>
            <attr name="incrementlabel" format="string"/>
        </declare-styleable>
    </resources>
```

My outer control includes labels and the ThirtySecondIncrement control.  I would like to make the outer control flexible enough that I could include the "countertype" style to the outer control.
Can I do this in xml or must I do it programmatically?  And if I do it programmatically how can I guarantee that it is done before the control is first used.  Here is the code to extract the xml attributes:

```
    public class ThirtySecondIncrement extends LinearLayout {
    final int COUNT_INTEGER = 0;
    final int COUNT_30SEC = 1;
    final int COUNT_1MIN = 2;
    //other code
    public ThirtySecondIncrement(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
            super(context, attr);
            TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attr, R.styleable.ThirtySecondIncrement, 0, 0);
            m_countertype = array.getInt(R.styleable.ThirtySecondIncrement_countertype, COUNT_30SEC);
            m_max = array.getInt(R.styleable.ThirtySecondIncrement_maxcount, MAXCOUNT);
            m_increment = (m_countertype == COUNT_1MIN) ? 2 : 1;
            array.recycle();
            Initialize(context);
        }
```

In a similar function in my IntervalEdit I could get an attribute relating to the counter and use a public function in ThirtySecondIncrement to set the countertype but, as stated, I'm wondering if there's a way to do this in xml.
thanks, in advance

Comment: Let me just clarify: IntervalEdit is a compound custom control that uses the ThirtySecondIncrement compound custom control and I wonder about adding xml to an instance of the IntervalEdit class that would allow setting xml of its enclosed ThirtySecondIncrement member.

Answer (score 0):

I waited a while but got no answer so I solved the problem by having a helper function in the nested control to enable to set the property at runtime.

```
    public void SetCounterType(integer countertype) {
    //after checking that countertype is a valid value
      m_countertype = countertype;
    }
```

then in the constructor for IntervalEdit:

```
    public IntervalEdit(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.IntervalEdit, 0, 0);
    //other attributes read here
      m_counterstyle = array.getInt(R.styleable.IntervalEdit_counterstyle, R.integer.counter_simple);
      (ThirtySecondIncrement)findViewById(R.id.tsi).SetCounterStyle(m_counterstyle);
```

The SetCounterStyle function in the first custom control only sets the variable and doesn't force a redraw enabling me to call it from within the including custom control's constructor.
Any, that's how I solved it.